# Difference in Unit test?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Is there any difference between these 3 section of codes?

In first and second one I am getting an error that Price_c variable doesnt exist but in third one I do not.

```java
List<Levis__c>  leviList = [Select Name, Price__c from Levis__c WHERE id= :levi.Id];
        
System.assertEquals(1100, leviList.Price__c);
```

vs

```java
List<Levis__c>  l = new List <Levis__c>();

l =[Select Name, Price__c from Levis__c WHERE id= :levi.Id];
        
System.assertEquals(1100, l.Price__c);
```

vs

```java
Levis__c j2 = new Levis__c ();

j2 = [Select Name, Price__c from Levis__c WHERE id= :levi.Id];

System.assertEquals(1100, j2.Price__c);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your third code block, your SOQL query is returning only one record (because you're filtering by the unique `Id` field) to one object, but in the others you are using a `List<Levis__c`. Update your assertions to check the first index to resolve the error:

```java
/* first */
List<Levis__c>  leviList = [Select Name, Price__c from Levis__c WHERE id= :levi.Id];
        
System.assertEquals(1100, leviList[0].Price__c);

/* second */

List<Levis__c>  l = new List <Levis__c>();

l =[Select Name, Price__c from Levis__c WHERE id= :levi.Id];
        
System.assertEquals(1100, l[0].Price__c);
```

Comment: haha yeah right. Thanks man. You are right. I am kind of new bee in Apex Programming. Luckily wrote a whole unit class. I knew all 3 are same but first two codes were giving me headaches as I was not able to find the error. But yeah to check the first index has resolved the error. You are a saviour .... :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the fact that your second example code won't compile for several reasons (and should be giving you an error before "Price__c doesn't exist"), the main issue/difference is that example 2 is using a `List` as opposed to an instance of your `Levis__c` SObject.

Lists (and the other collection types, Maps and Sets) do not have fields of their own. Their job is to store multiple instances of a specified type, and to provide methods that allow you to add/remove items, inquire about the number of items in the collection, retrieve items, etc...

If you want to access data stored in an object inside of a collection, you first need to pick *one* item from the collection.

Invalid: `myList.targetField__c`
Valid: `myList[0].targetField__c` (provided that your list is not empty)

Typically, if you are working with collections, you'll have a loop to iterate over the collection (to give you a single record to work with at a time, without the need to write `myList[0]`, `myList[1]`, ..., `myList[n]`)